# Unable to locate package linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

Started boot-repair on live-usb, removed grub, and then was instructed to write in terminal `sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda5" apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux` but I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux
```

and it says grub is still absent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot-repair can't complete a repair under Ubuntu Gnome 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453436/boot-repair-cant-complete-a-repair-under-ubuntu-gnome-14-04)

Answer (score 4):

The original command should not be,

```
apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux
```

It should be,

```
apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc
```

If you run `apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux` command, `apt-get` tries to find and install the packages `grub-pc` and `linux`. But there is no such `linux` package available.

```
E: Unable to locate package linux
```

The above part from the error report is your clue.

The presence of "linux" in the install line is a bug in boot-repair, and should be reported there.

Comment: thnx alot, it was too confusing for beginners like me. your answer did great help.

Answer (score 1):

The command line reported by boot-repair *is*
    `apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux`

Whether or not the word "linux" should be there is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

When prompted by Boot-Repair, please type this command in the terminal:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc
```

linux command in a terminal on 1 line only. In your question it appears broken on 2 lines.

Comment: I do write it on one line, it appears broken because it is the end of the line (I copy paste actually)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Boot Repair and found that if I omit the word "linux" from the end of the command, then it installs properly. For some reason Boot Repair says you should include the word (but again, you should not).