# Boot-repair can't complete a repair under Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, boot-repair

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 on my computer. The installation program wouldn't recognize my Windows 8.1 installation, but it could see the NTFS-partitions.
I figured that I could make the necessary partitions for Ubuntu manually, and then later make both systems boot-able with boot-repair.

Now my computer boots into Ubuntu Gnome, and I followed this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to install boot-repair with the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

(Notice the trusty/saucy-line, this is because boot-repair ain't on launchpad for 14.04 yet)

It all went well until boot-repair asks me to insert the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux
```

After this the terminal says

```
E: Unable to locate package linux
```

Can anybody tell my why I get this error, and how I should proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not

```
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux
```

It's

```
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc
```

There is no such package named `linux`.

Comment: Okay, this seems to be the solution. The strange thing is that the boot-repair script specifically ask for that command. It must be a bug in boot-repair.

Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: who told you to run that command?

Comment: The boot-repair application itself. When I went through the different steps, it told my two times to run a command in the terminal, by showing a little window where I could copy the text from. The second time it showed my the exact command I posted here. sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux

Answer (score 1):

Yes... boot-repair *does* specifically request that one enter

```
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux
```

I agree that it does not work unless you remove the linux from the end of the line, so I assume that it's a typo. Hopefully, it still fixes the problem correctly.